# Online-only ClickOnce app not updating through web link

Tags: winforms, windows-7, clickonce

I'm working on a ClickOnce app that's set to online-only. I publish it to an internal IIS server, with an HTML page in the same directory that contains this link:

```
<a href="MyAppName.application"></a>
```

The deployment looks like so, with all files except the `HTML` page generated by my project's `publish` target:

```
MyAppName
 -> Application Files
     -> MyAppName_2213_20_0_65
         -> <The published files>
 -> default.html
 -> MyAppName.application
```

When I click the link, the app runs immediately without any confirmation prompt, and I see from the about box that it's the old version. When I browse to the file share and launch MyAppName.application by double-clicking on it in Explorer, I get the prompt asking me if I'd like to run it, and then it downloads and I get an error:

> Unable to install this application because an application with the same identity is already installed. To install this application, either modify the manifest version for this application or uninstall the preexisting application.

As part of the build process, I set the `InstallUrl` property of the project to `http://ourserver/MyAppName/MyAppName.application`. Is that wrong? Should it be the HTML page that contains the link? How is it determining the "identity" that's generating a conflict?

Since the app's online-only, it's not installed and doesn't show up in the Programs and Features control panel (and therefore that part of the error message doesn't apply).

I'm new to ClickOnce, so let me know if I left out some helpful information.

**Update**

If I run `mage -cc` from a Visual Studio command prompt, the new version launches instead of the old one.

**Update 2**

As I poked around more, I'm seeing something that looks wrong, and could be the problem. I see the following two lines in my MyAppName.application file (the deployment manifest):

```
...
  <assemblyIdentity name="MyAppName" version="1.0.0.0" ...
...
  <dependency>
    <dependentAssembly dependencyType="install" codebase="Application Files\MyAppName_2213_20_0_65\MyAppName.exe.manifest" size="82044">
      <assemblyIdentity name="MyAppName.exe" version="1.0.0.0" ...
...
```

You can see the mismatch above. It's deploying to `MyAppName_2213_20_0_65`, but it thinks the version number of the `exe` is `1.0.0.0`. I'm not sure why it thinks that. My project includes a file that gets generated as part of the build with this line:

```
[assembly: AssemblyVersion("2213.20.0.65")]
```

Then, to set the published version number, I have this in my `csproj` file:

```
<Target Name="BeforePublish">
  <GetAssemblyIdentity AssemblyFiles="$(TargetPath)">
    <Output TaskParameter="Assemblies" ItemName="MyAppAssemblyInfo" />
  </GetAssemblyIdentity>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ApplicationVersion>%(MyAppAssemblyInfo.Version)</ApplicationVersion>
    <InstallUrl>$(INSTALL_URL)</InstallUrl>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Target>
```

Does the assembly version listed for my executable even matter? If it does, why is it stuck on 1.0.0.0, and could that be affecting the download of updated versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My second update put me on the right track. The problem was indeed the incorrect version number for the `assemblyIdentity` attributes. To fix it, I'm no longer using a `BeforePublish` target. Instead, I'm passing in the ApplicationVersion when I call MSBuild:

```
"%msbuild_path%" MyAppName.csproj /target:Publish /p:ApplicationVersion=%VERSION%
```